# Angular: custom decorator to override behavior of built-in ViewChild

Tags: angular, angular-decorator

I am trying to write a "shorthand" decorator/annotation to use instead of `@ViewChild`, by overriding its default behavior with `{static: true}` (I am migrating an Angular 4 app to 13, which has several `TemplateRef`s (mainly passed as column cell-templates into `ngx-datatable`s, built using [ngx-semantic](https://ngx-semantic.github.io/)).

Since I do not modify any other behaviors of `@ViewChild`, I tried the simple/dumb approach of:

```
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

export function StaticChild(selector) {
  return ViewChild(selector, {static: true});
}
```

And using `@StaticChild('selectorExpr')` on the relevant component fields, instead of `@ViewChild('selectorExpr', {static: true})`.

This works, but not for all cases; it works if I annotate a field in one component and use/pass the reference within **the same component**, but if I access such a reference (through a getter) from **another component** and use it in the latter, it does not get propagated. (If I instead use the standard `@ViewChild..` with static opt on one of these "indirectly" referenced fields, it starts getting propagated as expected; so I'm guessing it has something to do with the annotation metadata population/association.)

I would like to understand what I am missing/doing wrong with my `StaticChild` definition.